Where can I ask a question about the internet and web mechanics? Like domain name registration and domain commerce?
The question asks it all.
I want to know where Elon Musk bought his x.com domain from and how much he paid for it.


I want to know where Elon Musk bought his x.com domain from and how much he paid for it.

I'd say the question isn't a good fit for the model of the network
Ah so in theory, you might get referred to Super User. I'd close it if it was asked there, since I feel this falls under the definition of the sort of question you shouldn't ask.
It is a question I'd consider mindless social fun, and not a practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face.
Its also, rather trivial to google and if you're indeed curious, you can easily find your answer that way, as far as is public.

Thank you.  I didn't realize that a Google result would do this for me.
My apologies.  At least you prevented me from contaminating some SE site.
